# get SSL certificate for mail server, while already having it for domain

Tags: centos, postfix, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have already achieved an SSL certificate for my domain by `certbot`. the configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@xxx.com
DocumentRoot "/root"
ServerName xxx.com
ServerAlias www.xxx.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/xxx.error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/xxx.access_log" common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.xxx.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =xxx.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

now I have installed Postfix SMTP Server and like to get a certificate for `mail.xxx.com` as well. how to get ssl certificate for my mail server now?

I have already tried the following command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d mail.xxx.com
```

which outputs:

```
Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.
```

Comment: The way you are using certbot it requires http for authentication. You either need to run a web server on port 80 of the mail server or use an alternate method like DNS validation.

Comment: Is something running on port 80 of your mail server at the moment?

Comment: @davidgo I have installed apache which is listening on port 80

Comment: Why aren't you using the Apache plugin for certbot then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton you mean `sudo certbot --apache`?

Comment: Yes, that. I'm surprised you didn't already do that!

Comment: I also tried that and got error for `mail.domain.com` as I have mentioned here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1032428/

Answer (score 1):

You can try stopping Apache, so port 80 would be free and certbot can bind to it.

```
sudo systemctl stop httpd

sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d mail.xxx.com
```